# Add space between two particular <td>s

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table

```
<tr>
   <td>One</td>
   <td>Two</td>
   <td>Three</td>
   <td>Four</td>
</tr>
```

How can I add some space between the `<td>`s '*Two*' and '*Three*' alone?

Comment: Set padding on CSS or add `&#160` ( its space ) after text Two.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 20px;
}​
```

But that won't work if you need to work with background color or images in your table. In that case, here is a slightly more advanced solution (CSS3):

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

It places a transparent border to the right of the cell and pulls the background color/image away from the border, creating the illusion of spacing between the cells.

*Note: For this to work, the parent table must have `border-collapse: separate`. If you have to work with `border-collapse: collapse` then you have to apply the same border style to the next table cell, but on the left side, to accomplish the same results.*

Answer (score 11):

Simple answer: give these two tds a style field.

```
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td style="padding-right: 10px">Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
<td>Four</td>
</tr>
```

Tidy one: use class name

```
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td class="more-padding-on-right">Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
<td>Four</td>
</tr>

.more-padding-on-right {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Complex one: using nth-child selector in CSS and specify special padding values for these two, which works in modern browsers.

```
tr td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 10px;
}​
```

Comment: Technically, this does not add spacing between the `td` elements as requested, even though it spaces their contents apart. The difference between these concepts is relevant e.g. if the cells have background or border set. There is no way to really set spacing between two `td` elements without setting spacing between all cells.

Comment: You are right. Since there is no way to give some extra space BETWEEN two particular tds, this is the only thing I can come up with.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Strictly speaking, true. But practically speaking my solution does address the issues you mention, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

you have to set cellpadding and cellspacing that's it.

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr> 
<td>One</td> 
<td>Two</td> 
<td>Three</td> 
<td>Four</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not only does that not do what the question asked at all, those attributes should *not* be used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

my choice was to add a `td` between the two `td` tags and set the `width` to `25px`. It can be more or less to your liking.  This may be cheesy but it is simple and it works.

Comment: This is the simplest, easiest, most clear and precise answer here. I used this also! Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SQQzw/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td:nth-of-type(2) {
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me. The simplest way would be to add `<td>`s in between with `width = 5px` and `background='white'` or whatever the background color of the page is.

Again this will fail in case you have a list of `<th>`s representing table headers.

Comment: It won't fail if you add the same amongst the <th>'s with the same widths. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

td:nth-of-type(n) { padding-right: 10px;}

it will adjust auto space between all td