# Table td border visible and invisible same row

Tags: html, css, html-table, visible

I have 2 tables with data, in the table under I want to calculate the amount of 3 columns. These 3 td have a border while the 4 on the left and the 1 on the right don't have a border. It looks fine like this, but I had to add some pixels to the size of the td on the left (4px) which is not something I really want.

Any advice on how to do this?

[image]

Code

HTML

```
 <table id="Tbl_UriJou_Goukei" class="goukei">
                <tr>
                        <td width="240"></td>
            <td width="55"></td>
            <td width="34"></td> **<!-- 30 + 4 px to align 商品合計 td -->**
            <td align="right" width="80">商品合計:</td>
                        <td align="right" class="sum" width="80">...</td>
            <td align="right" class="sum" width="80">...</td>
            <td align="right" class="sum" width="80">...</td>
            <td width="50"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
```

CSS

```
table.goukei {
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: normal;
}

table.goukei td  {
    padding: 5px;
}

table.goukei td.sum  {
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC; }
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `colspan` HTML attribute.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to place the data in a 2nd table?

Answer (score 0):

You can give in `<table>` which's `<td>` right side you want spacing by `cellspacing="4"` as a attribute. Or you can give padding to it .

For Exampler :

```
td.some-class {
   padding : 0 4px 0 0;
}
```

OR you can look here

[Add space between two particular <td>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320036/add-space-between-two-particular-tds)

Comment: thanks, but I guess adding some extra pixels to the td before it would be easier...